# Rails 4 getting values through ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this simple function in my **HomeController**

```
def get_ids
    @ids_arr = [1,2,3,4]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :nothing => true } 
      format.js   { render :nothing => true }
    end
end
```

and I have very simple .js file **main.js**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ids',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

but output of my ajax call is empty string

do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HomeController:**

```
def get_ids
  @ids_arr = [1,2,3,4]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :nothing => true } 
    format.json   { render json: @ids_arr }
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  get 'ids' => 'home#get_ids'
```

**main.js**

```
$(function () {
    $('#test_ajax').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ids',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log("error");
        }).always(function () {
            console.log("complete");
        });
    });
});
```

**in view**

```
<a href="#" id="test_ajax">Get IDs</a>
```

I've tried in my rails 4. It works.

Comment: @Jakub Kohout, I have fixed to change in format.json. Because if you use format.js, it means you can display your data respond in get_ids.js.erb file.

Comment: Let me know the result, I have added the full code.